# How to get stage details of a particular build in azure devops using VSTeam module?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I tried to use below method, but it didn't worked

Invoke-VSTeamRequest -ProjectName 'MyProjectName' -area Build -resource stages -id 'StageID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using this command [Invoke-VSTeamRequest](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Invoke-VSTeamRequest), which allows you to call any TFS/AzD REST API. All the Auth and Route Structure is taken care of for you. Just provide the parts of the API call you need.

However, there must be the existed target Rest API and then we can call it. And by reference to this doc: [Azure DevOps Services Build REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), there is not existed API aiming for your wanted feature, that's why your method doesn't work.

In addition, currently the stage details in the UI page come from many APIs, the details cannot be available by single API, we can only view it from UI page now from [build yaml pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#stage).

Comment: Hi Pritha, Does my answer explain your confusion? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.